# Missing assemblies in Dynamics 4.0.7 Web Service

Tags: c#, dynamics-crm, dynamics-crm-4

I have added a web service reference for MS Dynamics 4.0.7. I'm developing in VS 2010 and I'm missing Microsoft.CRM.SDK.Messages namespace. Everything up to Messages namespace works fine.

I'm working on a basic example which uses WhoAmIRequest and WhoAmIResponse classes, but I can't get any further due to missing assemblies.

Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The namespace which is missing is part of the SDK assemblies. It is not included in the web reference. I assume you refer to the class [MessageName](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb955670.aspx).

Keep in mind that you could use either the web reference or the sdk assemblies, but not both at the same time as you will get type conflicts in this case.

Comment: Thank you for this. I was under the impression that SDK assemblies would be a part of web reference. But web reference is just for running CRUD routines.

Answer (score 0):

The WhoAmIRequest and WhoAmIResponse messages are included in the web reference (crmservice).

You can get the current user like this:

```
    using CrmWebReference; //whatever you called it

    ... 
//crm is the name of my CrmService object

    WhoAmIRequest userRequest = new WhoAmIRequest();
    WhoAmIResponse current = (WhoAmIResponse)crm.Execute(userRequest);
    systemuser currentUser = (systemuser)crm.Retrieve(EntityName.systemuser.ToString(), current.UserId, new AllColumns());
```